# Como fazer uma string no AppSettings e utiliza-la depois

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso fazer uma string no AppSettings, e depois utiliza-la, por exemplo, a string no AppSettings é esta:

> string exemplo = "exemplo"

E pegar o valor que está na string do AppSettings e coloca-la num textbox, como posso fazer isto?

Comment: string teste = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exemplo"] ?

Comment: No app.config:
<appSettings>
    <add key="exemplo " value="exemplo"/>
  </appSettings>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só usar [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[chave]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings).

```
using System.Configuration;

// outras coisas 

public static void AlgumaFuncao()
{
    var valor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exemplo"];        
    meuTextBox.Text = valor.ToString();
}
```

Lembrando que o config da aplicação precisa estar parecido com isto

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="exemplo" value="Alguma string de exemplo"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: AppSettings["exemplo"] - Não é uma string ?

Answer (score 0):

**No seu `app.config`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="exemplo" value="exemplo"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**No código C#:**

```
string exemplo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exemplo"];
```

Lembre-se de adicionar refêrencia a `System.Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar em um txtbox deverá fazer isso:

```
txtbox.text = Properties.Settings.Default.teste;
```

Para salvar é assim:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.teste = txtbox.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```